# problema al enviar email con codeigniter4

Tags: php7, xampp, codeigniter-4

Hola amigos trato de enviar un email con la librería que tiene ci4 en Email.php ya realice la configuración del archivo pero me sale esto Incapaz de enviar email usando PHP mail(). Su servidor puede no estar configurado para enviar correos usando este método.,  en el host 000webhostapp  si funciona perfecto, el error esta en tratar de enviarlo en local con xampp, asi lo tengo configurado:

```js
<?php
namespace Config;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
class Email extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromEmail;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $recipients;
    /**
     * The "user agent"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $userAgent = 'CodeIgniter';
    /**
     * The mail sending protocol: mail, sendmail, smtp
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $protocol = 'smtp';
    /**
     * The server path to Sendmail.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $mailPath = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    /**
     * SMTP Server Address
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPHost='smtp.gmail.com';
    /**
     * SMTP Username
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPUser='mi email';
    /**
     * SMTP Password
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPPass='mi clave';
    /**
     * SMTP Port
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $SMTPPort = 465;
    /**
     * SMTP Timeout (in seconds)
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $SMTPTimeout = 20;
    /**
     * Enable persistent SMTP connections
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $SMTPKeepAlive = false;
    /**
     * SMTP Encryption. Either tls or ssl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPCrypto = 'ssl';
    /**
     * Enable word-wrap
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $wordWrap = true;
    /**
     * Character count to wrap at
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $wrapChars = 76;
    /**
     * Type of mail, either 'text' or 'html'
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $mailType = 'html';
    /**
     * Character set (utf-8, iso-8859-1, etc.)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $charset = 'UTF-8';
    /**
     * Whether to validate the email address
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $validate = false;
    /**
     * Email Priority. 1 = highest. 5 = lowest. 3 = normal
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $priority = 3;
    /**
     * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CRLF = "\r\n";
    /**
     * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $newline = "\r\n";
    /**
     * Enable BCC Batch Mode.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $BCCBatchMode = false;
    /**
     * Number of emails in each BCC batch
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $BCCBatchSize = 200;
    /**
     * Enable notify message from server
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $DSN = false;
}
```

me gustaria saber como hacer veo en otros foros respuestas  en el host , pero la coloco como aparece en las respuestas pero no me funciona no se como hacer para que desaparezca ese error. eh probado varias respuestas pero no eh acertado aun en una que pueda entender y corregir mi codigo

Comment: ¿"tratar de enviarlo en local con xampp"? ¿`000webhostapp` no está localmente en xampp? no entiendo.

Comment: Hola Sal, si envialo local con xampp osea en modo desarrollo, unicamente funciona si se sube al hosting , desde alli si envia el email con la configuracion que tiene, si trato de enviarl el email desde mi pc local me sale ese error, pero si debe funcionar desde otro pc lo envie anteriormente en local , pero esta vez no funciona sale ese error

Comment: Revisa en tu `php.ini` si tienes configurado [`SMTP`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mail.configuration.php) y `smtp_port`.

Comment: lo tengo asi: [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

Comment: Debe apuntar a un servidor smtp, ¿tienes uno en localhost?

Comment: No se, lo vi en youtube asi lo configuraron, en si xampp actua como servidor local y el mismo puede enviar, pero la verdad no se que sucedera con ese error

Comment: Regularmente pasa porque necesita la extensión openssl para realizar el envío, debes habilitarla en tu php.ini `;extension=openssl`, quitando el `;` del inicio